# XCode AppDelegate returns sigabrt in 5.0 Simulator, but works fine in 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, ios-simulator, sigabrt

I updated my XCode to 4.2 and would like to use Simulator 5.0 instead of 4.3.

I coded a tabbar application with 5 tabs, but pushed another view as first view through appdelegate.

Now I have the problem that it all works fine in simulator 4.3, but gives me an error in simulator 5.0:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); SIGABRT

objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x7d626b0 (object 0x7d1e750, a NSException)
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0xe99ee sp=0xbfffdee0] for exception 0x7d62690
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0xe99ee sp=0xbfffdee0] for exception 0x7d62690
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x7d62690 at 0xe9bac
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x7d5cd30 (object 0x7d1e750, a NSException)
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0xe9b9c sp=0xbfffdee0] for exception 0x7d5cd10
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x1a02db3 sp=0xbfffec20] for exception 0x7d5cd10
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0xe9b9c sp=0xbfffdee0] for exception 0x7d5cd10
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x1a02db3 sp=0xbfffec20] for exception 0x7d5cd10
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x7d5cd10 at 0x1a02e46
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: rethrowing current exception
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x1a02e0f sp=0xbfffec20] for exception 0x7d5cd10
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x1a02e0f sp=0xbfffec20] for exception 0x7d5cd10
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler
objc[3441]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x1a02e38 sp=0xbfffec20] for exception 0x7d5cd10
```

I localized the problem to be in the AppDelegate at:

```
AppDelegate *app = [AppDelegate getApp];
    app.tabController.selectedViewController = connNavController;
```

I also tried to push the controller by using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

but I always get a SIGABRT.

Cleaning Target, restarting etc. doesn´t work.

Please help if you have a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

did you try substituting

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

with

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Comment: AppDelegate loads a login screen first. after login there is the delegation that causes the SIGABRT.

Comment: AppDelegation is done this way:
    AppDelegate *app = [AppDelegate getApp];
 [app.navigationController pushViewController:cntrl animated:YES];
 [cntrl release];
No problem in ios4.3, SIGABRT in ios5. ;(

Answer (score 0):

Little can be tell from your stacktrace, but when you are using the property `selectedViewController` that view controller most be in the `viewcontrollers` array of the `UITabBarController`, if it is not in the array it will throw an error like in this case.

So make sure you have this in your code:

```
myTabBar.viewcontrolleres = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myViewController, more, nil];
```

Comment: It is in the code. When I leave my delegation out and just showing the tabbar it works. The I created buttons in navigation bar with the same Appdelegation as before. As soon as the buttons are pressed I get the same SIGABRT. Seems like I can´t use that type of delegation in the whole app.

Comment: As I can see there are not all tabbarControllers in the array and when I try to call one of them I get the sigabrt. ios4.3 just overrides that. is there a possibility to override it in ios5, too?